# Programatically delete [permenantly] a TFS work item

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

Whilst I'm aware that there is a command line tool to permenantly delete a TFS work item. (e.g. [How to delete Work Item from Team Foundation Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638154/how-to-delete-work-item-from-team-foundation-server/3319028#3319028))

Has anyone been able to achieve the same action programatically using the TFS 2010 API DLLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shai Raiten has blogged about this [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2010/02/19/tfs-api-part-21-delete-work-item-using-workitemstore-demo-application.aspx), where he makes use of `DestroyWorkItems(ids)`.

It is advisable that you proceed with extra caution in your implementation, since this can severely mess your installation. One could argue that constructing such a tool deviates from best practices.

Answer (score -1):

You can also [use PowerShell to bulk delete work items](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deepakkhare/archive/2015/11/12/tfs-data-clean-up-bulk-delete-destroy-work-items.aspx):

> Copy and paste below script in a PowerShell file (with .ps1
>   extension), update the variable values mentioned in the list #4 below
>   and run the command from a machine where witadmin tool is installed
>   (Generally available after visual studio installation). Open
>   PowerShell command window and execute the script.
>   Note: Account running below script should have team foundation administrator or collection administrator access.
>
> ```bsh
> ########TFS Work Items Bulk Destroy Automation Script##########
> #Notes:
> #1) This script requires to setup file/folder path, validate the file/folders path before running the script
> #2) start the powershell window as Administrator and run the script
> #3) This script requires share and admin access on the destination server, make sure your account or the account under which script is
> #    executing is member of admin group on the destination server
> #4) Update following:
> #   4.1: $CollectionURL
> #   4.2: $WitAdmin tool location
>         # For VS 2015, Default location is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
>         # For VS 2013, Default location is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE
> #   4.3: $WI_List
> #   4.4: $logfile
> ####################
>
> $CollectionURL = "http://tfs:8080/tfs/CollectionName"
> $WitAdminLocation = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE"
> $WI_List =  Get-Content "C:\WI_List.txt"
> $logfile="C:\log.txt"
> $ExecutionStartTime = Get-Date
> $WICount = 0
> "## Starting WI Destroy @ $ExecutionStartTime ##"| Out-File $logfile -Append
> "Collection URL: $CollectionURL" | Out-File $logfile -Append
> foreach ($WIID in $WI_List)
>     {
>         CD $WitAdminLocation
>         .\witadmin destroywi /collection:$CollectionURL /id:$WIID /noprompt
>         "WI ID: $WIID Destroyed" | Out-File $logfile -Append
>         $WICount = $WICount + 1
>         Write-Host "$WICount Work Items Deleted"
>     }
>
> $ExecutionEndTime = Get-Date
> "## WI Destroy Command Completed @ $ExecutionEndTime ##"| Out-File $logfile -Append
>
> $TotalExecutionTime = $ExecutionEndTime - $ExecutionStartTime
>
> "Total Work Items Deleted: $WICount"   | Out-File $logfile -Append
>
> " Total Execution Time: $TotalExecutionTime"  | Out-File $logfile -Append
>
> ##End of script##
> ```